# File Uploading to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am working in `Asp.Net` and i want to upload file to server it shows me the error

> The `SaveAs` method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path 
>   ~/192.zzz.zzz.z/CaheadServices/ImagesNIINIR.jpg' is not rooted.

here is my code

```
   protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            fup.SaveAs("~/192.zzz.zzz.z/CaheadServices/Images" + fup.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        } 

    }
```

Please Help me out.

Comment: If you want to put it somewhere under your exposed document tree, you'll want to use HttpServerUtility.MapPath (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to get the fully qualified path of the directory you'll save your file into.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save file on a Shared path. And using a relative URL which must not be existing in your application's folder. So your path should be like below example

```
 String  pathAndFile = "\\\\Server\\Folder\\";
 FileUpload1.SaveAs(pathAndFile);
```

Also as your code will be on `IIS` and you must provide permission to `IUSER` to upload files on shared location.

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            fup.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/192.zzz.zzz.z/CaheadServices/Images" + fup.FileName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Always a good idea to state what you're suggesting, rather than expect people to have to read an entire copy of the code and figure out the one small change